# A notational problem of a double integral

Tags: integration, notation, definite-integrals

What does the following double integral mean?I don't quite understand the notation.

$$\int_0^1dy\int_\sqrt{y}^\sqrt{2-y^2}f(x,y)~dx~.$$

Does it equal to

$$\int_0^1\int_\sqrt{y}^\sqrt{2-y^2}f(x,y)~dx~dy~?$$

Comment: Some people use the notation $\int dx f(x)$ for integrals, altough I think this way of writing it makes it way more complicated. Your first integral does not look like this notation, altough I think this is what is meant by it. How I understand the notation, though, I don't think it's the same as your second integral, though, as $\int_0^1 dy = 1$ and hence $\int_0^1 dy\int_a^b f(x,y)dx = \int_a^b f(x,y)dx$.

Comment: @dinosaur: The convention is to read from right to left; in such a case, the integrand in the $y$ integral is non-constant because the the $y$-dependent integration limits in the $x$ integral (never mind that $f$ also depends on $y$).

Comment: Ron knows this (antiquated) notation, so he is right.  You are correct saying what it is equal to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trained to place the differential first, which makes me stand out like a sore thumb in Math.SE.  I like this notation because it is very clear which differential goes with which integral.

In your example, I would agree that

$$\int_0^1 \, \int_{\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{2-y^2}} f(x,y) \, dx \, dy = \int_0^1 dy \, \int_{\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{2-y^2}} dx \, f(x,y)$$

The reversal of the $f$ and the $dx$ in your first double integral is of no consequence.